# Loading long shellcode in memory in C

Tags: c, shellcode

I want my shellcode to run in x86 arch, but char array in C has a limit of ~16k, while my shellcode is longer. I broke the string on 2 arrays and started as follows:

```
char n1qwgimnb8i[] = "\x75\x6d\xf2\x34...";
char n1qwgimnb8i1[] = "\x74\xdf\x39\x37...";

void *zx1rwsnvf4l = VirtualAlloc(0, sizeof n1qwgimnb8i + sizeof n1qwgimnb8i1, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

memcpy(zx1rwsnvf4l, n1qwgimnb8i, sizeof n1qwgimnb8i);

memcpy((char *)zx1rwsnvf4l + sizeof n1qwgimnb8i, n1qwgimnb8i1, sizeof n1qwgimnb8i1);

CreateThread(NULL, 0, zx1rwsnvf4l, NULL, 0, NULL);
```

I compiled with cl and got no errors, but when I start a final .exe it crashes. What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: Presumably you're generating those strings with a program or script, so why not generate array syntax instead?  `unsigned char foo[] = { 0x75, 0x6d, 0xf2, 0x34, ... }`.  I don't think any decent compiler would have a low limit on the size of that.  It would also avoid the unwanted terminating nul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String-style initialization of `char` array like

```
char hoge[] = "foo";
```

automatically add terminating null-character at the end of data and this example is equivalent to

```
char hoge[] = {'f', 'o', 'o', '\0'};
```

Therefore, an extra `0x00` byte will be inserted between the two arrays and it may cause trouble.

The line

```
memcpy((char *)zx1rwsnvf4l + sizeof n1qwgimnb8i, n1qwgimnb8i1, sizeof n1qwgimnb8i1);
```

should be

```
memcpy((char *)zx1rwsnvf4l + sizeof n1qwgimnb8i - 1, n1qwgimnb8i1, sizeof n1qwgimnb8i1);
```

(`- 1` should be added to have the copy start from right after the original data without terminating null-character)